# how to set a value to <s:hidden > from the action class without using list and iterator in struts 2?

Tags: struts2

In action class i am reading value from the database.
Let's say "abc".Now the "abc" value should be populated to jsp page.i.e "abc" value should set to s:hidden field in the jsp page.
Since it is single value , i don't want to use `List` in the action class.
Is there any other way to do that  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you want to use a list? Just provide the appropriate getter like:

```
public Object getAbc(){
   return abc;
}
```

and in your page access it with simple OGNL expression like:

```
<s:hidden name="filedYouWantToSetThisValueTo" value="%{abc}"/>
```

Hope I got it right.

Comment: But i think hidden field take value as "abc".It is not desired.Value should be what "abc" containing.It might be assigned "xyz"(abc = "xyz").

Comment: @Jagan I forgot value should be forced for OGNL mapping: `value="%{abc}"`